# django CMS: integrate autocomplete in template

Tags: javascript, django, django-cms, django-autocomplete-light

I want to integrate autocomplete-light into a template in django cms

my view in app "doctor":

```
def search(request):
   q = request.GET.get('q', '')
   queries = {}
   queries['person'] = Person.objects.filter(name__icontains=q)[:6]
   return render(request, 'search.html', queries)
```

urls.py (CMS)

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^autocomplete/', include('autocomplete_light.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  # NOQA
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap',
        {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CMSSitemap}}),
    url(r'^select2/', include('django_select2.urls')),

    #url(r'^doctor/', include('doctor.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),

)
```

urls.py (app doctor)

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^', views.search, name='search'),

]
```

search.html

```
<input type="text" name="q" id="navigation_autocomplete" style="width: 270px;font-size: 16px;" />
<style type="text/css">
  /* cancel out django default for now, or choices are white on white */
  #header a.choice:link, #header a.choice:visited {
    color: black;
  }
</style>
<span class="separator">Person</span>
  {% for p in person %}
     <a class="block choice" href="{{ p.url }}">{{ p.name }}</a>
  {% endfor %}


<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#navigation_autocomplete').yourlabsAutocomplete({

         url: '{% url 'NoIdeaWhatToEnterHere' %}',

       choiceSelector: 'a',
     }).input.bind('selectChoice', function(e, choice, autocomplete) {
            document.location.href = choice.attr('href');
     });
     });
</script>
```

search.html is an apphook into a CMS page with the url "/en/list/" or /ru/list/" depending on the language.

What url do I have to set in the javascript part?
Currently I always get the NoReverseMatch error.

EDIT:

As requested the Error details:

```
NoReverseMatch at /en/search/
Reverse for 'search' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://primo2-caliph007-8.c9users.io:80/en/search/
Django Version: 1.7.10
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'search' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Exception Location: /home/ubuntu/workspace/virt7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 468
Python Executable:  /home/ubuntu/workspace/virt7/bin/python
```

Comment: Would you please provide the error stack trace?

Comment: I will gladly add the stack trace but I need to understand which value to put in the javascript. From the docs it says it should be the url of the view I use for the search. The url name then would be "search".

Comment: But due to the use of the CMS, urls.py in app doctor is disconnected from the main urls.py (see the line that I had to comment out). The CMS is handling the urls.py. Thats why I do not get how to set the parameters here.

Comment: my intention is to integrate this example into a djamgo cms apphook page: https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/docs_rewrite/navigation.html

Comment: Is app doctor connected to a page via an app hook? If so you could refer to it's URLs using the ID set on that page. Something like `{% url 'appdoctor:search' %}` where `Application instance name` in the page settings is `appdoctor`

Comment: That's a good hint. I could solve it this way.